# $X(C) = \{\text{nilpotent elements in $C$}\}$ is not a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I am try to prove that 
$X(C) = \{\text{nilpotent elements in C}\}$ is not a scheme.

I have proved that it is local, so what makes it is not a scheme must be the open cover stuff. And I think it is covered by $X_n(C) = \{x|\text{$x^n=0$ in C}\}$. So I think it is covered by an infinite union of affine schemes. Therefore, I think the problem is that the cover is not open.

But even if I could prove this obvious cover is not open. It is still not sufficient to prove that $X$ has no open affine cover. And I have no idea for finding some contradiction assuming $X$ has an open affine cover.

So how to show that $X$ has no open affine cover? Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the space $C$?

Comment: @Joppy $X$ is an $R$-functor for a ring $R$, and it is applied on $C$ where $C$ is an $R$-algebra.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way to prove it.  Take your favorite field $k$ and let's base-change to $k$: supposing $X$ is a scheme, consider the scheme $Y=X\times \operatorname{Spec} k$ as a scheme over $\operatorname{Spec} k$.  For a $k$-algebra $C$, then, $Y(C)$ is the set of nilpotent elements of $C$.  As you say, this is covered by the affine schemes $Y_n=\operatorname{Spec} k[t]/(t^n)$ of elements $x$ such that $x^n=0$.  Now the key observation is that each $Y_n$ has only one point, and so when you consider $Y$ as the nested union of the $Y_n$, this means $Y$ has only one point as well.  In particular, $Y$ must be affine, so it must be $\operatorname{Spec} A$ for some $k$-algebra $A$.  Then $A$ would be the universal $k$-algebra with a nilpotent element: there is an element $a\in A$ such that for any nilpotent element $x$ in any $k$-algebra $C$, there is a unique homomorphism $A\to C$ sending $a$ to $x$.  This is impossible, since we must have $a^n=0$ for some particular $n$ and then $a$ cannot be mapped to $x$ if $x^n\neq 0$ but $x^N=0$ for some $N>n$ (e.g., $x=t$ in $k[t]/(t^N)$).

Comment: Maybe I have some misunderstandness. But may I please ask if this $Y$ is equivalent to taking $R$ to be $k$, so if $Y$ is an $R$-scheme for all $R$, then it must be a $k$ scheme? If so, I think if we take an $k$-algebra $C$ such like $k[x]/\langle x^2\rangle$. Then $0$ is not the only nilpotent so $Y(C)$ is not a single point.

Comment: Yes, $Y$ is equivalent to taking $R$ to be $k$.  When I refer to "points", I mean in the sense of points of Spec of a ring being prime ideals, not in the sense of the functor of points.

Comment: It seems that you are talking about some intrinsic notion
of a point of a functor without mention of an $k$-algebra $C$. It seems unfamiliar to me. If possible, may I please ask what is the "points" here refers to, and how does it related to "prime ideals"？

Comment: Oh, it seems you have never seen that definition of schemes at all then.  Instead of defining schemes as functors, you can define them as certain locally ringed spaces.  If $A$ is a commutative ring, then $\operatorname{Spec} A$ is the set of all prime ideals of $A$ equipped with a certain topology and sheaf of rings.  General schemes are then locally ringed spaces that are locally isomorphic to spaces of the form $\operatorname{Spec} A$.

Comment: For the purposes of this answer, the relevant fact is that a scheme like $\operatorname{Spec} k[x]/(x^n)$ has _no_ open subschemes besides itself and the empty subscheme (and this is a consequence of $k[x]/(x^n)$ having only one prime ideal).  So if you had any nonempty open subscheme of $Y$, it would have to entirely contain every $Y_n$ and thus be all of $Y$.

Comment: Thanks! The version of general scheme that I have learnt is: A functor $X$ such that  (1) $X$ is local; (2) $X$ have an open affine cover which consists to what you said above about general schemes. But it does not mention anything about prime ideals. That is where I fell confused.

Comment: That today students may learn that affine schemes are a type of functors but are not told that these schemes  have a certain relationship with prime ideals makes me feel very old...

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg The definition of "affine schemes" we learned was "A representable functor $Alg_R -> Set$". Prime ideals were barely mentioned at all throughout this course.